# How to return a snapshot Image as a Byte array in a function using Swiftui?

Tags: xcode, swiftui, mapkit

I have the following function that takes three parameters to generate a snapshot image by using MKMapSnapshotter. the function generates the snapshot correctly, but I want to return the generated snapshot as a Byte array. I think it can be performed by using callback, completion handler or something like that, I appreciate if there is any answer.

```
func generateImageSnapshot(location:CLLocationCoordinate2D, width: CGFloat, height:   CGFloat) {
let options = MKMapSnapshotter.Options()
options.camera = MKMapCamera(lookingAtCenter: location, fromDistance: 300, pitch: 0, heading: 0)
options.mapType = .standard
options.size = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
let snapshotter = MKMapSnapshotter(options: options)
snapshotter.start() { snapshot, _ in
let mapImage = snapshot?.image
let finalImage = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: options.size).image { _ in
mapImage?.draw(at: .zero)
let pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: nil, reuseIdentifier: nil)
let pinImage = pinView.image
let point = snapshot?.point(for: location)
pinImage?.draw(at: point!)
}
return finalImage.pngData() // This line is needed to be returned by the function
}
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem with the following code fragment:

```
func generateImageSnapshot(location: CLLocationCoordinate2D, width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat, completion: @escaping (Data?) -> Void) {
        let options = MKMapSnapshotter.Options()
        options.camera = MKMapCamera(lookingAtCenter: location, fromDistance: 300, pitch: 0, heading: 0)
        options.mapType = .standard
        options.size = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
        let snapshotter = MKMapSnapshotter(options: options)
        snapshotter.start { snapshot, error in
            guard let snapshot = snapshot, error == nil else {
                completion(nil)
                return
            }
            let mapImage = snapshot.image
            let finalImage = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: options.size).image { _ in
                mapImage.draw(at: .zero)
                _ = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: nil, reuseIdentifier: nil)
                let pinImage = UIImage(systemName: "mappin")
                let point = snapshot.point(for: location)
                pinImage?.draw(at: point)
            }
            let imageData = finalImage.pngData()
            completion(imageData)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?